# AngularJS: Accordion not loading properly when navigating between pages

Tags: html, css, angularjs, angular-ui-bootstrap

I am trying to navigate between two pages in angularJS using href. Both pages have accordions and they aren't loading properly when I navigate from one page to another. The accordion work fine when I refresh the page or when I directly go to the page (without navigating from another page).

Here is my code:

```
 <a href= "{{domainName}}/#/Reports/Reports?subscriptionID={{subscription.SubscriptionID}}">
                                        <div class="pull-right btn btn-xs btn-primary" id="btnEditSubscription">
                                            <i class="fa fa-pencil" aria-hidden="true"></i>&nbsp;&nbsp;Edit Subscription
                                        </div>
                                    </a>
```

So I want to go to Reports page from this button click. Reports page has accordion. This is how the accordion in Reports page looks when navigating after the button click:

[image: Error Loading Accordion]

This is how the accordion should look like:
[image: When accordion loads properly]

It looks like when navigating between pages I am missing .ui-accordion class.

Please help!!

Thank you

Comment: are you using ui-router?

Comment: No I am not using ui-router. This is how mine looks:

angular.module('myApp', ['ngGrid', 'ngGridster', 'ngRoute', 'ui', 'ui.bootstrap', 'ngAnimate', 'highcharts-ng'])

Comment: might help your app to use it, take a little time to setup up, but you could reuse the accordion template without having to load it for every page change.[ui-router](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router)